# Send notifications to specific user groups

Tags: android, notifications

I'm fairly new to android development, and I have this idea in mind, but I'm not very sure whether this is possible or not:

I would like to create an app where each user can create a group of users(which consists of his contacts).

The group information will be stored on the device itself. 
Then, I want to make an option that when a user in a certain group clicks a button, all the members of that certain group get a notification (I don't need a text message, just a simple notification).

I would like to know if its possible? If yes, what are the requirements? Will I need a server for that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is learn communication, you can go through this, [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start).
And yeah, you'll need a basic server to keep your "group" in sync.